# What happens to $\|Ax -b\|^2$ when $x$ is subjected to constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

How do we check if the function still remains convex?

Do we calculate the Hessian under the constraints?

Suppose I put up a constraint on $x$ to have $|x_i| < 1$ for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. In the book, it says that now it becomes a quadratic programming problem with an affine constraint. What does it mean in simple terms and how do I approach solving this?

Comment: If a function is convex on the entire space, then it is also convex on a convex subset...

Answer (score 2):

I think that part of the confusion here is that the term "convex" is used to describe three different categories of things: convex *functions*, convex *sets* or *constraints*, and convex *optimization problems*. There are close relationships between these three concepts, so the multiple use of the term "convex" is justified. Nevertheless, it sometimes causes confusion.

A convex *function* is a function $f(x)$ satisfying
$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)
\quad\forall x,y\in\mathop{\textrm{dom}}(f).$$

A convex *set* is a set $X$ satisfying
$$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in X \quad \forall x,y\in X.$$
Hopefully the similarity to the definition of a convex function is obvious. In fact, a function $f$ is convex if and only if its *epigraph* $\mathop{\textrm{epi}} f \triangleq \{(x,y)\,|\,f(x)\leq y\}$ is a convex set.

A convex *constraint* is an expression, usually an equation or inequality, that describes a convex set. For instance, each of your constraints $|x_i|\leq 1$ is a convex constraint. The intersection of convex sets is always convex; likewise, the combination of your $n$ constraints describes a convex set---a hypercube, in fact.

Finally, a convex *optimization* problem involves minimizing a convex *function* subject to zero or more convex *constraints*. (There are variations, but for the purposes of this discussion this will suffice.)

So to answer your question: the *function* did not change just because you now have some constraints you would like to apply. Rather, you have constructed a convex *optimization problem* that involves minimizing that function subject to $n$ convex constraints. This problem is more difficult to solve in practice than if the constraints weren't there. But your text is correct; this is a *quadratic programming problem*, and there are a wealth of resources (text and software) that describe these problems and how to solve them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the function $|w| <= 1$ a convex constraint? Usually $Ax <= b$ is an affine subspace which is also convex but is this constraint a subspace too?

Comment: Again, be careful with your categories. $|w|\le 1$ is not a function, it is a constraint, an inequality. It can be represented equivalently by two affine constraints $w\le 1$, $w \ge -1$.

Comment: Also $Ax\le b$ does not define an affine subspace in general. $Ax=b$ does.

Comment: Note that if you define a convex function has Michael has here, you need to have a convex domain.  A function $f$ might be convex on some convex subset of its domain but not on its entire domain.  You can redefine the domain and consider it a different function on the restricted domain, or you can define a function to be convex on a specified convex set.